# Java SE and web session

Tags: java, session

I'm implementing web-parsing app in Java SE and I need to work with web sessions.
Please, help me, how can I receive, store and send session ID and how can I use it to browse web like logged user?
I'm using HTTP and HTTPS, URL class and reading through InputStreamReader:

```
URL page = new URL("http://" + url);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(page.openStream()));
```

I want to implement it in Java SE, no Java EE.

Comment: you can use Apache HttpComponentshttp://hc.apache.org/.

Answer (score 0):

This would actually depend on the kind of sites you are going to be parsing.
Sites can send back a session id in the url, or even in the web pages.
also web sessions objects typically reside on the server.
You would need to look at the sites and then determine how you approach this...

Comment: Session ID is set to cookie